# How to convert the current date (now) to a numeric value?

Tags: ruby

I want to get the current date (full date with precision to seconds), and then convert it to a numeric value.

Comment: In Ruby, `Date` ne `date`. `Date` is a class that doesn't have a time value. `DateTime` or `Time` both have date and time values. So, your question isn't quite clear. Perhaps you should use "timestamp" instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numeric value like a unix timestamp?

```
Time.now.to_i
```

Further info: As Paul Rubel points out in the comments, since this is the unix timestamp representation, the number returned is the number of seconds since the epoch, 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

**UPDATE**

To get a time object back from the timestamp:

```
Time.at(1303247533)
```

Comment: Nicer than my answer - deleted mine.

Comment: To be clear, that's the number of seconds since the epoch, 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

Comment: so how would I get it back to a string representation?

Comment: Just to clarify, `Time.at(1303247533)` returns a Time object, not a string. You can use `to_s`, or `strftime` or several other methods in that class to convert from the object to a string representation of it.